# Проблема с загрузкой видео в Video js player. Ошибка video.es.js:100 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, videojs

Пытаюсь использовать video.js player в vue для видео в формате m3u8. Половина загружается нормально, другая половина видео почему-то выдаёт 2 ошибки:

> video.es.js:100 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) audio append of 159111b failed for segment #0 in playlist 0-http://rmq-mc-mcrai.sberdevices.ru/hls/content-gb3_b/MuVi/e6e7/4ce6/55b4/4a6b/a26f/7b387835252a.mp4/index-v1-a1.m3u8 mi {code: 3, message: "audio append of 159111b failed for segment #0 in p…/55b4/4a6b/a26f/7b387835252a.mp4/index-v1-a1.m3u8"}

> video.es.js:100 VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported. mi {code: 4, message: "The media could not be loaded, either because the …rk failed or because the format is not supported."}

Опытным путём установлено, что видео не грузится, когда в видео что-то не так со звуком (если открыть по ссылке в vlc - плейре, то оно воспроизводится, но без звука). Есть ли какие-то пути это решить, чтобы видео загружалось всё равно (можно даже без звука). Можно ли как-то программно на стороне клиента это обработать, отделить видео от звука при возникновении ошибки?

Мой код:

```
<template>
 <div class="player-block__player" id="capture">
     <video id="my-video"  class="video-js" controls preload="auto"                   
 >
  <source type = "application/x-mpegURL">
     </video>
 </div>
</template>

import videojs from 'video.js'
export default {
 methods: {
  playerInit(){     
    this.player = document.querySelector('video');
    let source = document.querySelector('video source');
    source.src = this.currentFilm.url_360;
                    
    this.videojsPlayer = videojs('my-video',{
                            controls: true,
                            playbackRates: [0.25, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
                            });
          },
}
```

Comment: гуглили? отключали AdBlock?

Comment: Adblock отключен. Гуглил, конечно, я бы тут не стал вопрос задавать, если бы пару дней до этого не прогуглил вопрос. Вот тут была подобная проблема, но насколько я понял, решения там не появилось https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/6560

Comment: Это не помогло https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/5606#issuecomment-440142607 ?

Comment: Не помогло. У меня формат m3u8, а не .mp4. Но в любом случае я пробовал вставить и type: 'video/mp4', и type = "application/x-mpegURL"